# To DMZ or not-DMZ on new web site

Tags: sql-server, security, asp.net-mvc, dmz

We are about to release a web application for our users, and are trying to figure out if others put their servers in a DMZ, or just keep it off the domain behind the firewall and greatly restrict access via firewall rules?  Has anyone here found any cons to just restricting access via firewall rules and O/S perms?

Note that this site is an ASP.NET MVC front-end with SQL Server back-end.

**Also** - this is an HR/Finance application, and the database back-end contains our most valuable data.  From a security perspective, I'd rather give the world root access to intranet than allow access to the database server.  As a result, my original plan was to skip using a DMZ and only opening up port 443 on the firewall to the web server ... this seemed no worse than putting the db server on the DMZ with the web server.

Comment: Should be on Serverfault, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, the configuration is like this:

```
Internet facing servers connected to Firewall's DMZ Port
Trusted servers (SQL, AD, etc) connected to Firewall's Trusted/LAN Port
Internet connected to Firewall's WAN port
```

Then, the Firewall is configured to route between those subnets, and allow access according to the ACLs you define.

Comment: So the database and web server communicate through the firewall?  Doesn't that slow things down?

Comment: Yes. It does. You need an enterprise grade firewall if you expect to push lots of traffic through.

Comment: That said, you can get a LOT of throughput on a medium size firewall for a few thousand dollars.

Comment: We ended up putting our web server for internal users on the same server as the database, but putting our web server for external users in the DMZ.  Makes speed ridiculously fast for internal data entry users, while allowing scalability for the thousands of external users.  Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I do usually not use a DMZ, but only a firewall. The account that the IIS application pool is running on is already restricted.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is what's the best practice?

It doesn't matter where things are placed it comes down to one thing. i.e. How you've secured it.

One firewall rule could open everything up, or close everything down.
Maybe you need to look at it from a different perspective.

Do you trust your employees enough to have direct access to those servers without a firewall restricting access between them.  Same goes for internet.  If that's the case put them both in a DMZ.

Personally I like them on the same subnet without a firewall between them because it ensures maximum performance.  But, if the web server was compromised it leave the DB server more open than if it was on the safe LAN side.  Are their other services need to be available on the DB server from the LAN side like RDP?  depending on where it sits you might have to open ports up from lan to DMZ to allow access etc.

Answer (score 0):

Golden Rule: If it can be reached from the Internet and there is no practical reason not to do so - put it in the DMZ. The idea being that if the machine is compromised it should not be possible to reach the internal network. In effect, it's kind of like a double firewall.

Comment: OK, but what about the database?  If the database is in the DMZ, we really have very little security benefit vs. just opening a port ... but if it's on the internal network we have a performance hit from all db traffic traveling through the firewall and back.

Comment: Don't worry about performance hit by firewall.  Most firewalls are extremely fast. Security is more important at this point.

Comment: @Jess, Matt's comment is correct and if you ever get to the point of having a detectable performance hit from the firewall it would be cheaper to replace it with a higher performance one that it would be to clean up after an attack. You are also wrong about the security aspect. Having a DMZ is virtually the same as having a separate and isolated network for the server(s) that faces the Internet. It simply comes down to limiting the damage an attacker could do by not allowing them into the LAN.

Comment: @John - I understand, but the only data we care about is what is sitting on the database server.  By putting the web server on the DMZ, we have to create rules that allow database server access across the firewall (in this case, just from the web server) ... particularly since the database server would need to be opened up for write-access from internal clients as well.  Even if the db server is on its own dmz, it's the same.  In my view, this seems less secure than putting both the web and db servers on the internal network and just opening up port 443 to the web server.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Jess, without a DMZ, if someone gains control over your server (don't kid yourself that it can't happen) they are inside your network. With the same server in a DMZ they are outside your network and have a whole new system they have to try and penetrate before they can get to the inside.

Comment: @John - but by putting a DMZ in place, we increase the attack surface against our most important asset - the database ... right?  Database communications are going to occur over the firewall (i.e. between user apps and the database or the web server and the database).  By putting the web server and database server behind the firewall, the only packets across the firewall are for port 443 to the web server.  You're speaking generally, but in this specific case I don't see how a DMZ offers more protection than a single port being opened.

Comment: Plus ... the sys admin has to create a far more complex set of rules, and with greater complexity almost always comes greater exposure.

Comment: We ended up putting our web server for internal users on the same server as the database, but putting our web server for external users in the DMZ. Makes speed ridiculously fast for internal data entry users, while allowing scalability for the thousands of external users. Thanks for the ideas!